# Is there a good way to get the latest iOS app icon for 3rd party apps that might or might not be installed?

Tags: ios, api, app-store, app-store-connect

As the question states – can I grab the latest Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, Vine, Google, TripAdvisor, etc. iOS app icons from an API effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a call to itunes API and get the icon and screenshots:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350
```

Comment: I was thinking this. It is not so effective for the use case but this is probably the best answer so I'm going to accept this.